# DistCP Fail to get block MD5

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, distcp

There was one hidden file in the source cluster:
`.part-1-1458.inprogress.xxxxxxxxx`

Actually, this file was generated by Flink, and file size is 0.

When we use DistCp to copy the directory, we met an exception
`Caused by: java.io.IOException: Fail to get block MD5 for xxxxxxxxxxx`.

After we removed this file, DistCp worked correctly.

Could DistCp handle the empty hidden files? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems DisCp cannot handle empty files.

```
java.io.EOFException: Premature EOF: no length prefix available
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.vintPrefixed(PBHelper.java:2468)
```

```
  public static InputStream vintPrefixed(final InputStream input)
      throws IOException {
    final int firstByte = input.read();
    if (firstByte == -1) {
      throw new EOFException("Premature EOF: no length prefix available");
    }

    int size = CodedInputStream.readRawVarint32(firstByte, input);
    assert size >= 0;
    return new ExactSizeInputStream(input, size);
  }
```